# Hiding events in p:schedule with css

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces

I hava a `p:schedule` that shows 2 sorts of events.
The list with `Events` is filled with a `Try` method like this:

```
//ResourceEvents
eventResourceAvailPerDay.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(reason, dateBeginConverted, dateEndConverted, "resource"));

//WaitingItemEvents
DefaultScheduleEvent newResourceEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(reason, dteBeginOrWaitingItem, dteEndOrWaitingItem, orWaitinglist.getWKey());
newResourceEvent.setStyleClass("waitingitem");
eventResourceAvailPerDay.addEvent(newResourceEvent);
```

The 2`Events` has the following css-classes as created above: `resource`, `waitingitem`

The following is what I am trying to achieve:
In Month view I only want the `waitingitem` class to be visible, so hiding the `resource` class, also if possible to override JSP 2.0 that these events(`waitingitem`) are non-clickable.
In weekview and dayview only the `resource` class should be visible

I already have the following css code which does not give me the result that I want:

```
.waitingitem, .schedule .waitingitem .fc-view-month, .waitingitem a {
    display: none;
}
.waitingitem, .schedule .waitingitem .fc-view-agendaWeek, .waitingitem a {
    display: block!important;
}
.resource, .schedule .resource .fc-view-month, .resource a {
    display: block;
}
.resource, .schedule .resource .fc-view-agendaWeek, .resource a {
    display: none!important;
}
.resource, .schedule .resource .fc-view-agendaDay, .resource a {
    display: none!important;
}
```

any suggestions?

**UPDATE** //working css

```
schedule .fc-view-month .resource, 
.schedule .fc-view-agendaWeek .resource,
.schedule .fc-view-agendaDay .resource,
.schedule .fc-view-agendaWeek .waitingitem
.schedule .fc-view-agendaDay .waitingitem
{
    display: block;
}
.schedule .fc-view-month .waitingitem 
{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: `display: true` isn't valid CSS : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

Comment: oké thx, i've changed that but doesnt make any difference. seems to be something wrong with the .fc-view-agendaWeek and day class I think.. tried alot of combinations and still no result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-month .resource,
#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-agendaWeek .waitingitem,
#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-agendaDay .waitingitem
{
    display: none;
}

#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-month .waitingitem,
#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-agendaWeek .resource,
#id-of-a-parent .fc-view-agendaDay .resource
{
    display: block;
}
```

Note : `#id-of-a-parent` can be what ever you want, just to make the rules more important.

Does that make sense? I still can't test on your setup.

Comment: gosh i'm so bad with css, thx for the help, updated post with working code!